# Silence GORM logger for single query

Tags: logging, go-gorm

I know that I can change (and silence) the gorm logger like this:

```golang
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
  Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Silent),
})
```

However, I'd like to change `LogMode` for only a single query. Much like `db.Debug().Find(...)` would make sure a single query will be logged. But I would like to disable logging for a single query.

Creating another gorm instance might be an option for some databases (not SQLite, though).

Background: I like the logging of GORM, but I have a single query which I know is very slow and very long (multiple MB) and I don't what that to end up in the log...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var answer Answer
err := db.Session(&gorm.Session{Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Silent)}).Where("question_id = ?", questionID).First(&answer).Error
```